# When a web service call was invoked in BlackBerry, application hangs

Tags: java, web-services, rest, blackberry

I am creating my very first blackberry application that tries to connect to a rest web service. I tried the example I found in the internet. Please refer to this link: http://mobile-development.org/index.php/blackberry/how-to-call-restful-web-services-in-blackberry

I tried to implement it in my simple BlackBerry application which is the one that is automatically created when you create a new BlackBerry project in BlackBerry Plug-in for Eclipse IDE. I just placed the code (literally copied and pasted it) in my button, that when clicked, will execute such code. But, when I click the button, the application hangs.

When I implement a code that simply outputs "Hello" in the output log, the application works perfectly fine. What is the reason behind it? Do I need to run the web service call in a separate thread? Please help. Thank you in advance.

--------------------PLEASE READ BELOW----------------------

I noticed that my application hangs because it waits for a response from the web service call of at least 2 min. I read through this: http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0 -- and added "deviceside=true" at the end of the url (http://yourwebserviceurl.com;deviceside=true"). It works fine now. Maybe the proper implementation for this is to do the task in background or in a separate thread and set the timeout which I do not have a knowledge on it yet. I'm still confused on whether to set the deviceside to true/false. Should I set the deviceside to true when I'm running my app in a simulator then just change it to false if I want it to run in an actual device? That is for me to discover for now or you can help me out on this one as well. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code they have given is in for HTTP connection , It is totaly fine, But what we need to do  call this code in a thread , because ui works also in thread by which by which it got stuck. 
So you need to use thread concept here. 
Look at Samples provided into

```
Eclipse helios\plugins\<sdk version>\components\samples\com\rim\samples\device\httpdemo
```

Whenever you wants to update UI In a background thread , use

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            <Update UI>
        }
    });
```

I hope it may help you .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the HttpDemo example and provided the url from the example I gave. I ran it in a simulator, but it can't retrieve anything for it reaches a timeout. Error message says: "java.io.InterruptedIOException: Local connection timed out after ~ 120000". Is there a way I can test any example regarding web service calls in my project? I'm very new to BlackBerry development. I just want a very simple application so I can understand how it really works before proceeding to a much complicated scenario.

Comment: whatever you wants to execute in separate thread in , It will not stuck UI.

Comment: Will I just place the example code (http://mobile-development.org/index.php/blackberry/how-to-call-restful-web-services-in-blackberry) inside the run() method? Or am I doing it wrong? Because I already implemented that, still the application hangs. With regards to the HttpDemo, it doesn't retrieve anything from the url I am providing because it reaches a timeout. Really a newbie here.

Comment: Ooops! I did something stupid here. I forgot to edit my code because I edited it beforehand and placed the code inside synchronized (this) {}. I used the original example code again and placed it inside the run() method and it now no longer hangs. I can now retrieve the response! Thank you very, very much for your help!